# Insert css if logged in

Tags: perl

I have this Perl script that I didn't write (nor can I write Perl), inserts a logout link if you're logged in:

```
sub print_loginform {
  $web_content .= qq{


                 </form>
  };
}

if ($logged_in_as) {
  $addlink = '<a href="/logout">Logout</a><a href="/account/">My Account</a>';

}
$web_content .= qq{
        <div id="menu">
                <div id="menuheader">Menu</div>
                <a href="/">Home</a>
                <a href="/online/">Who's online?</a>
                <a href="/highscores/">Highscores</a>
                <a href="/rules/">Rules</a>
          <a href="/about/">About</a>
                <a href="/guilds/">Guilds</a>
                <a href="/houses/">Houses</a>
          <a href="/shop/">Donations</a>
          <a href="/forum/">Forum</a>
                <a href="/lost-password/">Lost Password</a>
                <a href="/create-account/">Create Account</a>$addlink
        <div id="menufooter"></div>




};

if (!$logged_in_as) {
  &print_loginform();
}
$web_content .= "</div>";
```

Would there be a way to add some inline css when the user is logged in to do something really hacky and just `display:none` the loginpanel?

I tried this:

```
if ($logged_in_as) {
      $addlink = '<a href="/logout">Logout</a><a href="/account/">My Account</a>';
       $removelogin = '<style type="text/css" media="screen">.loginpanel:display:none;</style>';
    }
```

Safe to say it didn't work but since I'm not a Perl programmer I can't really figure this out, this is a total shot in the dark for me, and I feel like a bit of noob for even coming and asking for help.
The documentation I tried to find on Perl was sparse at best too.

Here's Mathew's code, this doesn't work (probably my fault)

```
sub print_loginform {
  $web_content .= qq{


                 </form>
  };
}

if ($logged_in_as) {
      $addlink = '<a href="/logout">Logout</a><a href="/account/">My Account</a>';

    }
$web_content .= qq{
        <div id="menu">
                <div id="menuheader">Menu</div>
                <a href="/">Home</a>
                <a href="/online/">Who's online?</a>
                <a href="/highscores/">Highscores</a>
                <a href="/rules/">Rules</a>
          <a href="/about/">About RealOTS</a>
                <a href="/guilds/">Guilds</a>
                <a href="/houses/">Houses</a>
          <a href="/shop/">Donations</a>
          <a href="/forum/">Forum</a>
                <a href="/lost-password/">Lost Password</a>
                <a href="/create-account/">Create Account</a>$addlink
        <div id="menufooter"></div>

        <div class="loginpanel">
                     <form action="" method="POST">
                  <input type="hidden" name="auth" value="1">
                        Account Number:
                        <input type="text" name="user" value="" size=15>
                        Password:
                        <input type="password" name="pass" value="" size=15>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
            </div>            


                        <form method="POST" action="/character/">
                                <input type="hidden" name="page" value="character">
                                Character Search<input type="text" name="searchchar" value="" size=15><br><br>
                                <input type="submit" value="Look up">
                        </form>

};

if (!$logged_in_as) {
  &print_loginform();
  $web_content .= qq{<div class="loginpanel">
                 <form action="" method="POST">
              <input type="hidden" name="auth" value="1">
                    Account Number:
                    <input type="text" name="user" value="" size=15>
                    Password:
                    <input type="password" name="pass" value="" size=15>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
        </div>  
  };
}
$web_content .= "</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Well that's not correct css:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">.loginpanel{display:none;}</style>
```

You might also consider putting the login panel

```
   <div class="loginpanel">
                 <form action="" method="POST">
              <input type="hidden" name="auth" value="1">
                    Account Number:
                    <input type="text" name="user" value="" size=15>
                    Password:
                    <input type="password" name="pass" value="" size=15>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
        </div>
```

below this line

```
if (!$logged_in_as) {
  &print_loginform();
```

like so:

```
if (!$logged_in_as) {
  &print_loginform();
  $web_content .= qq{<div class="loginpanel">
                 <form action="" method="POST">
              <input type="hidden" name="auth" value="1">
                    Account Number:
                    <input type="text" name="user" value="" size=15>
                    Password:
                    <input type="password" name="pass" value="" size=15>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
        </div>  
  };
}
```

Comment: What would that do exactly?

Comment: It would make it so that the login panel would only appear when the logout link was not there.

Comment: it doesn't work im afraid, I'll edit my first post with the code I replaced

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hacking the css, maybe you can modify `$webcontent`.

```
if ($logged_in_as) {
      $addlink = '<a href="/logout">Logout</a><a href="/account/">My Account</a>';

}
$web_content .= qq{
        <div id="menu">
                <div id="menuheader">Menu</div>
                <a href="/">Home</a>
                <a href="/online/">Who's online?</a>
                <a href="/highscores/">Highscores</a>
                <a href="/rules/">Rules</a>
          <a href="/about/">About RealOTS</a>
                <a href="/guilds/">Guilds</a>
                <a href="/houses/">Houses</a>
          <a href="/shop/">Donations</a>
          <a href="/forum/">Forum</a>
                <a href="/lost-password/">Lost Password</a>
                <a href="/create-account/">Create Account</a>$addlink
        <div id="menufooter"></div>
};

if (!$logged_in_as) {
   $web_content .= qq{<div class="loginpanel">
                 <form action="" method="POST">
              <input type="hidden" name="auth" value="1">
                    Account Number:
                    <input type="text" name="user" value="" size=15>
                    Password:
                    <input type="password" name="pass" value="" size=15>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
        </form></div>  
  };
}
$web_content .= "</div>";
```

I think you can omit the `print_loginform` function

Comment: that doesn't change anything.

Comment: Can you try printing the value of `$logged_in_as`?

Comment: I don't know how to do print that.

Comment: You can append it in `$webcontent`. `$webcontent .= qq{<p>debugging $logged_in_as</p>};`. Just remember to remove later.

Answer (score 0):

now remove this chunk:

```
    <div class="loginpanel">
                 <form action="" method="POST">
              <input type="hidden" name="auth" value="1">
                    Account Number:
                    <input type="text" name="user" value="" size=15>
                    Password:
                    <input type="password" name="pass" value="" size=15>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
        </div>
```

only the one that appears below:

```
<div id="menufooter"></div>
```

and finally reverse this part:

```
$web_content .= qq{<div class="loginpanel">
             <form action="" method="POST">
          <input type="hidden" name="auth" value="1">
                Account Number:
                <input type="text" name="user" value="" size=15>
                Password:
                <input type="password" name="pass" value="" size=15>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
    </div>  
 };
 &print_loginform();
```

though at this point you might as well remove print_loginform...